# pass environment variable to jar as command line arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I am running a jar which reads from properties in code. Now i want to set few variables at environment level and pass them as command line arguments to override properties. How can i do that?

ex:

```
java -jar test.jar  --server.http.host-url=https://x.com
```

in the above command, property value server.http.host-url is set as env variable with name "server.http.host.value".  how do i pass it as variable so it will resolved from env variables like this

```
java -jar test.jar  --server.http.host-url=${server.http.host.value}
```

Comment: You can create a shell or bat script based on your os. Fetch those property values from the script and start the jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the shell you are using the environment variable names might have different restrictions, but in most cases `.` is not allowed so name your variable something like `SERVER_HTTP_HOST_VALUE` for example and use it like this:

```
java -jar test.jar --server.http.host-url=$SERVER_HTTP_HOST_VALUE
```